# Flutter Web ListView sometimes cannot scroll up

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView that contains a couple of widgets of different type at the top, and then several ListTiles.

The ListView is created via this very basic code:

```
Flexible(
    child: ListView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        children: resultsWidgets,
        ))
```

The whole thing is renderded via Flutter Web.

The issue is that, sometimes, when I scroll up, the list scrolls up a bit and then kinda of automatically scrolls down a bit, leaving the user stuck at that point of the list.

This is what happens:

[image]

In order to "escape" this trap, the user has to grab the scroll cursor and move it really fast upwords: this way the list quickly jumps over a couple of list items and then continues to scroll up normally.

It's really difficult to identify a behaviour pattern, but:

- the app renders first the text of the list tiles (that are the results of a user query) *without* any word highlighted, and then, depending on some features of the user query, it dynamically computes the highlights server side with one request per item, and then, as the highlights are returned by the server, it updates the ListTiles with the widget holding the highlighted text - and so: if there is no highlight, the problem does not occur; if there are highlights, the problem occurs
- another thing that I noticed is that it tends to happen past the 9th - 10th ListTile - but this is a really approximate observation.

I tried to iteratively remove some widgets from the LitTiles in order to find out the culprit, but with no luck.

I replicated the problem with Firefox, Chrome and Safari.